# Saving string to overloaded brackets not changing field of object

Tags: c++, reference, overloading, variable-assignment, brackets

I have a problem in my code which i can't understand. I want to make a list of lists and use it like a two-dimensional associative array.

Something like this:

```
token["window"]["title"] = "Amazing!";
cout << token["window"]["title"]; //Amazing!
```

The second line works good. Data is readed from file. Problem is with the first instruction.

This is how i overload the **second** square brakcets:

```
TokenPair Token::operator[](string keyName){
    for( list<TokenPair>::iterator pair=keys.begin(); pair != keys.end();++pair){
        if(pair->key == keyName){
            return *pair;
        }
    }
}
```

As you see I return object of class TokenPair. To properly get the value from object (field TokenPair::value) i overload streaming and casting on string().

```
TokenPair::operator string() const{
    return value;
}
ostream & operator<< (ostream &stream, const TokenPair &pair){
    return stream << pair.value;
}
```

And as i say before **getting value works great**. Problem is with overloading operator of attribution:

```
TokenPair TokenPair::operator=( const string newValue ){
    value = newValue;
    return *this;
}
```

This method assing the value but it not remember that! For example:

```
token["window"]["title"] = "Ok";
```

will cause that inside *method TokenPair::operator=* variable *newValue=="Ok"* and after the first line even *value* is set to "Ok"; But when i later do:

```
cout << token["window"]["title"] ;
```

the field in TokenPair is still not changed. I want to ask: Why? Maybe iterators return a copy of that object? I don't know. Please help.

Comment: why not `map` of `map`s and just use a pre-made STL container that does exactly what you want?

Comment: Maybe because i never heard about it :c Can I make a two-dimennsional map? Map of maps? If yes that mean that I loose two one day of my life.

Comment: of course you can, that's the whole point of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to use a map-of-maps:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

const char inputString[] =
  "President 16 Lincoln "
  "President 1 Washington "
  "State Best Illinois "
  "State Biggest Alaska ";
int main () {
  std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string> > token;
  std::string primary, secondary, result;
  std::istringstream input(inputString);
  while( input >> primary >> secondary >> result )
    token[primary][secondary] = result;
  std::cout << "Abe " << token["President"]["16"] << "\n";
  std::cout << "Springfield, " << token["State"]["Best"] << "\n";
  std::cout << "Blank: " << token["President"]["43"] << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the `operator[]` returns a `TokenPair` by value, so when assigning you assign the new value to a temporary, not to the object stored in the list.

For this to work the `operator[]` should return a reference to the object you want to modify.

Comment: Yes. You have right. I knew that this is something with bad returning but i can't realize that asterisk after return instruction is insufficient to return a reference. After adding ampersant in declaration everything works as i need. Thanks for help :)

For future readers: i needed to add apersant in both _operator[]_. Not only for second brackets but also for firsts!

Comment: See the C++ FAQ `about operator[]`: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.10